# Piwik analytics tracker returning 403

Tags: analytics, http-status-code-403, matomo

I've just installed Piwik on a HostGator server, however during the installation I received an error notification that the tracker is returning a 403 status code. It then said to change some permissions and that I may need to contact the webhost to do this + to restart the server afterwards.

I contacted my webhost and they changed it however they can't restart the servers as I'm running the analytics on shared hosting. So the tracker isn't working and if I look at the console logs I see the following error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
http://analytics.mysite.com/piwik.php?action_name=...
```

Has anyone run into a similar problem? I've installed Piwik before on the same HostGator reseller account after contacting support, but it didn't work this time... Is there anything I can do from my side to fix this?

**Fixed:** I talked to them again today and asked them to do the same thing as I asked yesterday but this time it worked. Not sure what they were doing yesterday...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ask Hostgator to whitelist your account from mod_security.

Comment: You mean to whitelist the whole account rather than just the file? Because I did talk to them about this as instructed by Piwik...